# Replacing volatile with personal lock or Interlocked?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, volatile, interlocked

*Curiosity killed the cat, but I cannot resist... so I am asking :-).*

There is a lot of advices floating around to avoid `volatile`. So I wonder what is the correct/sane replacement -- personal lock, i.e. you have variable `x` so you wrap it in setter/getter with lock created just for it:

```
private volatile bool x; // previously
// replacement
private readonly object x_lock = new object();
private bool __x;
private bool x { 
   get { lock (x_lock) return __x; } ...
```

or it is better to use `Interlocked` methods (for reading using no-op `CompareExchange`):

```
private bool x { 
   get { return Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref __x,false,false); } 
   ...
```

*I use `bool` type to avoid discussion about the problems of compound operations, like classic increment of `int` when you have to read and write value in one atomic step. `volatile` does not help for such cases in the first place, so it is off-topic here.*

**Update**: this is quote from Eric Lippert blog "Volatile fields are a sign that you are doing something downright crazy: you’re attempting to read and write the same value on two different threads without putting a lock in place". This started my thinking (up to now I don't see anything crazy about flags). But absence of evidence is not evidence of absence...

Comment: You're missing the point of the advice. It's not about replacing volatile with some semantically identical option - that'd be rather pointless - but about avoiding the use of such low level constructs in the first place. Show a real use case and we can see what higher level constructs could be used to avoid the need for volatile. You might for example want to lock on a high level instead of worrying about all intermediate steps and how they might interact etc.

Comment: That said as all absolute advice there are exceptions. Sometimes volatile is the best solution or the performance tradeoffs are worth it.

Comment: @Voo, well in several places I use bool flag for signaling some state, like `isAborted`, `isConnected`, and so on. At some points I set such flag, in the others I read it, the requirement is to use the fresh value, not the cached one. I use locks on higher level (when needed), but when I need just a value from a flag (and nothing else) I started to wonder about those advices, and thus my question.

Comment: http://blog.coverity.com/2014/03/26/reordering-optimizations/  People are very surprised to learn that volatile reads can be re-ordered in this manner.

Comment: @Eric Most often - as seems to be the case here - volatile flags are used on their own, set in one thread and read in another to know e.g. when to terminate some long running operation. That pattern is reasonably simple although c# has that by now built in thanks to cancellation tokens so better use those. But yes the memory model is not simple and in more complicated scenarios particularly with multiple volatile fields one will most likely introduce bugs (an interesting follow up to your post would be to show how making r volatile wouldn't help under the CLR's memory model).